# Android database to listview clicklistener

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

Trying to get name when click on the list view which connected to database.
Searched for solutions but can't find exactly like this. Trying to solve for long time by myself but failed to do. My code:

```
public void v() {
            Cursor cursor = myDBHandler.getDatabaseCursor();

            final String []arr = new String[]{myDBHandler.getColumnName()};
            int idView[]=new int[]{R.id.lv_tv2};

            SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.lvlayout,
                    cursor, arr, idView);

            ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ap_Lv1);
            lv.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Cursor cursor1 = myDBHandler.getDatabaseCursor();

                        String s = cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndex(myDBHandler.getColumnName()));

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    cursor1.close();
                }
            });
        }
```

in MyDBHandler class getColumnName() method is:

```
public String getColumnName(){
        return COLUMN_NAME;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mCursor.moveToPosition(position);

String s = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(myDBHandler.getColumnName()));

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Trying to accept this answer but stack overflow is not making it public.